# Issues deploying .NET VSTO Excel addins, what is the best way to do it?

Tags: .net, vsto, excel-addins

When publishing an Excel Addin made in VS2010 using ClickOnce everything works out as it should. However when I update the code and do another publish. I encounter an error when opening Excel (see attached). Apparently the addin will not automatically update to the newest version, which is kind of the point of publishing this way. How can I get around this? And is there a better way to do it?

Note that if I manually run the setup.exe or vsto file from the publish dir, and then open Excel there is no problem, it's the automatic update that fails.

#### Error message (partial):

> The customization cannot be installed because another version is already installed and cannot be upgraded from this location...

Comment: I have tried to do the .NET Excel addin update both at home and on my work computer, and both produce the same error. That is it seems to register that an update have occured, but is not allowed to update for some reason, and instead closes the addin down. 

Again, manually clicking the setup.exe or vsto after update creates no issues. It is the automatic update that fails.

Answer (score 0):

The issue emerged as a result of having an installation of the add-in installed, and at the same time debugging another version of the same add-in. The solution was uninstalling the deprecated version, doing a clean in Visual Studio.After that debugging worked fine again.